# How to access private service which is provided by the component itself for unit testing

Tags: angular, unit-testing, dependency-injection

I have this component which provides a service by itself

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-component',
    providers: [MyService],
    ...
})
export class MyComponent { 
  constructor(@Self() private service: MyService) {}
  ...
}
```

During unit testing I noticed the following

```
beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [MyComponent],
        providers: [MyService],
    }).compileComponents();
    service = TestBed.inject(MyService);
});
```

That `service` is not the same instance as the service inside my component. I guess this makes sense, but I cannot find a solution for this, because for my tests I need access to that service inside my component. Any suggestions?

Comment: If it's self-provided, it's an implementation detail. If you need access to it, e.g. to inject a test double, it shouldn't be self-provided.

Comment: good point, I will reconsider my tests, thnx

Comment: @jonrsharpe there can be cases where services have to be component-level (altough rare). One example for that would be the `ChangeDetectorRef`, so i think this question is still valid.

Comment: @Mr.Manhattan I'm not saying otherwise, but the tests should be of the behaviour not the implementation.

Comment: @jonrsharpe i'd agrue that interaction with a locally provided service is part of the behavior, but that's ofc opionionated.

Comment: @Mr.Manhattan what that service _does_ as a result of that interaction is the behaviour, it's part of the thing you're testing. If it's considered a collaborator, it should be coming from outside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments above by @johnrsharpe its implementation detail so you shouldn't have to deal with it. Which is what I did, but I just found a way to do it. I don't need it anymore, but just for educational purposes I'll show it anyway:

```
let myService: MyService;

beforeEach(() => {
    myService = { ... };

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [MyComponent],
        providers: [MyService],
    }).overrideComponent(MyComponent, {
        set: {
            providers: [
                provide: MyService, useValue: myService
            ]
        }
    });
}).compileComponents();
```

Now you can use `myService` for mocking and spying!

Answer (score 1):

Self-provided is not the proper way to go there in that case. But if you absolutely have to do it this way, then you can get access like this:

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [MyComponent],
}).compileComponents();

const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
service = (fixture.componentInstance as any).service;
```

note that `private` is compile time only, so accessing it at runtime is not impossible. I'd still suggest to provide the service at module level though.

Answer (score 1):

Component service provider instance might be accessed with the next code:

```
  let service: MyService;
  let component: MyComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<MyComponent>;

beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [MyComponent],
        providers: [MyService],
    }).compileComponents();
    
});
 beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    service = fixture.componentRef.injector.get(MyService);

  });
```